# String replaceAll not working

Tags: java, string, replace

```
String val = "some random text.CHR(10)";
val = val.replaceAll("CHR(10)", "\n");
```

This is not replacing. I am expecting result of val as "some random text.\n" I'm using JDK 1.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `replaceAll` here. It takes a regex as first parameter. In regex, `()` are used to create groups. To match parenthesis, you need to escape it.

```
val = val.replaceAll("CHR\\(10\\)", "\n");
```

Or it's better to use `replace`:

```
val = val.replace("CHR(10)", "\n");
```

**Note:** Seems like, `String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` was not there in Java 1.4. So, you are left with only the first option.

Comment: can't use replace. due to some constraints.. I am uploading this java in oracle . so have to do this using replaceAll only

Comment: @Darshan. Then escape your `(` and `)`. Use `\\(` and `\\)` instead.

Comment: According to the [1.4.2 String docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), it takes `char` arguments only. You'll have to scroll down to the `replace` entry, the link is not SO link formatting-friendly.

Comment: How about `Pattern.quote()`? No... that's absent as well.

Comment: @ajp15243. Java 5 have added a method replace which takes a `CharSequence`. It's OP fault, or bad luck that he's still using `Java 1.4`.

Comment: Thanks @Rohit.. escaping ( parenthesis worked.. yes java 5 gives replace so could not use that.

Comment: @Darshan. Can I ask you why you are still using Java 1.4? We already have Java 7. And Java 8 is due release next year.

Comment: @RohitJain : I am calling java class from oracle stored procedure. to split json using json.jar ... since there is no reliable plsql json library... oracle version is 10.2 which suport jdk 1.4 ...so I am working on stone age jdk ;)   (using loadjava utility in oracle)

Comment: @RohitJain Java 8 has been due to be released "the next year" for the past three years :)

Answer (score 3):

You're not escaping the parentheses:

```
val = val.replaceAll("CHR\\(10\\)", "\n");
```

or

```
val = val.replaceAll("CHR[(]10[)]", "\n");
```

or `quote()` the pattern

```
val = val.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("CHR(10)"), "\n");
```